# Extracting data from SQLite using Entity Framework and Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, linq

I am currently working on a small C# project in Visual Studio 2017. I am using SQLite (ADO.NET version 1.0.110.0) along with EF6 DBProvider.

In this project I am simulating mouse clicks using the windows mouse_events. All the data I will be using are numbers that correspond to the desired pixel on which I want to click.

I want to interact with different windows that have different positions on the screen.

For the moment, using EF6 and LINQ I am capable of creating an instance of my DB. From there I extract the data that I am looking for, then for each item (In this case there is only one) I store it into a long.

My question are as follows ;

1. Is there a way to store the data that I am looking for directly into a variable rather than in a list and then to a variable?
2. Is there a way to access the variable "xClientCoords" outside of the method?
3. Is there a way to have this method return "xClientCoords" so that when I call it in another method further down it gives me the data I need?

Here is some sample code:

```
    public void FetchxClientCoords()
    {
        List<long> DBxClientCoord = new List<long>();

        using (BotDBEntities db = new BotDBEntities())
        {
            DBxClientCoord = (from c in db.ClientCoords where c.ClientNumber == 1 select c.xCoord).ToList();
            db.Dispose();
        }

        foreach (long xCoord in DBxClientCoord)
        {
            long xClientCoords = xCoord;
        }
    }
```

The expected end result is for me to be able to extract the x and y coords of each line when I ask for it.

For the moment the only way I have thought of it is to have this method twice, one for x and one for y.

I am very new to programming in general, I am sorry if this seems rudimentary.

If my explanation is lacking please tell me and I will try to reform it.

Comment: I see some problems in your code. If each item is unique you should not use list. Just use:  var dbxClientCoord = db.ClientCoords.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClientNumber  == 1). Than check if it is null before return it if (dbxClientCoord != null) { return dbxClientCoord.xCoord }. Your method also should be changed from void FetchxClientCoords to long FetchxClientCoords(...). Also client number is hard coded. Use it as parameter long FetchxClientCoords(int clientNumber).

Comment: Don't combine `using` and `Dispose` - the purpose of `using` is to call `Dispose` for you. Why are you doing `select c.xCoord`? You can do `select new { c.xCoord, c.yCoord }` to return both coordinates at once, then put them somewhere and work with them.